# import csv or sql thru phpmyadmin and skip PK?

Tags: mysql, import, primary-key, phpmyadmin

Is it possible to have phpmyadmin or other tool to import a csv or sql backup into an existing DB and skip the primary key or is this a manual, table by table process of inserting with queries and manually removing the primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways lead to Rome:
1 way:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.txt'
  INTO TABLE t1 (column1, column2, column3);
```

another way:

```
CREATE TABLE `import` (
  `column1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `column2` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `column3` varchar(128) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM CHARSET=utf8;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.txt'
  INTO TABLE import
  (column1, column2, column3);
INSERT INTO destination_table (columnA,columnB,columnC)
SELECT column3, column1, column2 FROM import;
```